# Trying to save NSManagedObject in appDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

i`m having a lot of trouble when i try to save a NSManageObject in the delegate, and worst problems trying to read the objects.
My Delegate is something like this:

```
@class ViewController;
@class RootViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
Trips *trip;
Garage *car;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) RootViewController *rootviewcontroller;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Trips *trip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Garage *car;

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
- (void) setCar:(Garage *)Car;
- (void) setTrip:(Trips *)Trip;
- (Trips *) gettrip;
- (Garage *) getcar;

@end
```

The complete methods to set and get are like this:

```
- (void) setCar:(Garage *)Car
{
    car = Car;
}
- (void) setTrip:(Trips *)Trip
{
    trip = Trip;
}
- (Trips *) gettrip
{
    return trip;
}
- (Garage *) getcar
{
    return car;
}
```

In the first view when i do:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
trip = (Trips *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trips" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[appDelegate setTrip:trip];
```

Seems to work OK, even if i do NSLog(@"%@", [appDelegate gettrip]); , it shows me the object without problemas. But when I try to read the same trip with [appDelegate gettrip] in other view, dosen`t work at all, in fact with NSLog it says that the object is the type Garage instead of Trips.

I don`t know what am i doing wrong. Help.

Comment: As an aside, `-[NSEntityDescription insetNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]` returns an `id` and therefore you do not need to cast the returning object.

Comment: Why go through all that rigmarole implementing methods and declaring member variables for the trip and car properties?  That's confusing and could be the source of your issue.  Simply set the object to the property and voila everything is handled for you: `appDelegate.trip = trip` and `appDelegate.car = car`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I did what you said and it`s better, but it seems like my problem is with the NSManagedObjectContext, because i`m having troubles saving data, adding a [context reset] y can save but i lost the data saved in the delegate. I try with [context redo] too, but it dosen´t work. Or save my changes or it saves the trip in the delegate. I can´t do both.

Comment: Then you need to ask a new question with the relevent bits of code in :) That will get more/new ore people looking at your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you making sure to save the context after you are creating the item? If you do not save it then I do not think that your new entity with be properly saved. In the code you are simply creating the object in the context, but you must save the context for its permanence:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
  //Handle error
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: While saving is important, this does not sound like a save issue since he is storing the entity in a property. In this code it is *just* another object.  There is no fetch or anything else that would mandate a save.

Comment: I try what you said, but it dosen`t work, in fact i try to access the data in the same view that i save and i can`t get it.

Comment: Perhaps you could turn on Zombies to see if the trip is getting deallocated somewhere.

Comment: How can i do that?, i don`t know how :P.

Comment: Under the "Product" menu click on "Edit Scheme" and then click on the "Diagnostics" tab, you should see an option for NSZombies and now there will be a log in the debugger that will alert you if an item is a zombie (has been deallocated)

Comment: Thanks, it seems like my problem is with the NSManagedObjectContext, because i`m having troubles saving data, adding a [context reset] y can save but i lost the data saved in the delegate. I try with [context redo] too, but it dosen´t work. Or save my changes or it saves the trip in the delegate. I can´t do both.

Answer (score 1):

If `NSLog` is reporting a different object then you need to look at where you are creating a Garage entity.

Perhaps you have a simple copy and paste error?

Answer (score 0):

while you are creating the object to be saved it doesn't look like you are actually saving the object to the persistent storage.

try this:

```
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error userInfo]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"EVERYTHING SHOULD HAVE SAVED PROPERLY");
}
```

now when you read the managedObject in the other views it should be there.

Comment: While saving is important, this does not sound like a save issue since he is storing the entity in a property. In this code it is *just* another object.  There is no fetch or anything else that would mandate a save.

Comment: I try what you said, but it dosen`t work, in fact i try to access the data in the same view that i save and i can`t get it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a memory management problem with your custom setters?

Do they need to be

```
- (void)setTrip:(Trip *)Trip {
    self.trip = Trip;
}
```

i.e. `self.trip =` instead of just `trip =` to use the property - otherwise I don't think it will retain your trip object and it will get autoreleased. Then, when yo come to use it later something else will be in that memory location.

Disclaimer - I'm still not 100% up with ARC yet so I might be wrong. It's worth a try though!

Comment: Thanks, i try but it crashes :/.

Comment: 'crashes' isnt a very helpful message - how does it crash;  where does it crash; whats the stack trace when it does?

Comment: Sorry for my answer, that isn`t the problem. It seems like my problem is with the NSManagedObjectContext, because i`m having troubles saving data, adding a [context reset] y can save but i lost the data saved in the delegate. I try with [context redo] too, but it dosen´t work. Or save my changes or it saves the trip in the delegate. I can´t do both.